# Background-transfer(Up-loader) for metro apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, background-transfer

The Background-transfer(Up-loader) for metro apps is not working when using https URI.
The same code works with http connection but with HTTPs it keeps on failing.
I get

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x80072EF3

I am using the same upload sample provide at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Background-Transfer-Sample-d7833f61 .

After a little search I found out that we have to include the certificate at `Package.appxmanifest`. But even that is not helping.

I am at the end of my wits to resolve this issue, so any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is resolved now. Its a simple DNS setting issue.

**If systems are behind Proxy:**
1. Go to gpedit.msc -> Under Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Network -> Network Isolation. 
2. Internet Proxy Servers for apps must be enabled with "IPaddress:Port" syntax. 
3. Run the command line: netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie

**If systems are not behind Proxy:** 
Please ensure that the DNS server settings in the system setting is proper. Meaning, for Preferred & Secondary DNS servers actual DNS server addresses must be provided and not the Proxy server address.